# Script to count number of incoming packets per second?

Tags: linux, scripting, debian, denial-of-service

Currently, I am trying to write a script that will run upon startup (Debian Linux), and count the number of incoming packets per second every ten seconds. The goal of this is to study different ways to mitigate DoS attacks, but I don't really know how to setup this base function of the script. I have done quite a bit of research into the best way to accomplish this, but really cannot find what I'm looking for. Since I'm a beginner in Linux scripting, can someone describe the process to accomplish this in layman's terms? Thank you so much!

Comment: [This](http://xmodulo.com/measure-packets-per-second-throughput-high-speed-network-interface.html) should help you get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

old_packets=0

while true; do
    packets=$(awk '$1 == "eth0:"{print $3}' /proc/net/dev)
    if ((old_packets)); then
        clear
        echo "$(bc <<< "($packets - $old_packets) / 10") packets/seconds"
    fi
    old_packets=$packets
    sleep 10
done
```

where `eth0` is the targeted interface.

### Edit:

from comments, if you want to disable `eth0` if the rate exceed 20 packets/seconds :

```
#!/bin/bash

old_packets=0

while true; do
    packets=$(awk '$1 == "eth0:"{print $3}' /proc/net/dev)
    if ((old_packets)); then
        clear
        # the variable rate contains the packets/seconds
        rate=$(bc <<< "($packets - $old_packets) / 10")
        echo "$rate packets/seconds"
        if ((rate>20)); then
            ip link set eth0 down
        fi
    fi
    old_packets=$packets
    sleep 10
done
```

[image] If you want to run this script at startup, you can edit your `/etc/rc.local` file, it's executed at the end of boot process.

Comment: Which variable is used to store the number of packets send per second? I'm super new to scripting, so some of the syntax is a little confusing to me.

Comment: It's computed every 10 secondes with the `echo "$(bc <<< "($packets - $old_packets) / 10") packets/seconds"` line

Comment: Okay. If I were trying to use the number of packets in an If Statement (I.E. if the number of incoming packets are >x, disable eth0 connection) how would I do that? Rather, which variable (if that term is applicable) should I use in the If Statement? I'm used to newer languages (C++, Java) that rely on variables to store information, so maybe that's why I'm hung up on that kind of logic. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: To clarify, the line `rate=$(bc <<< "($packets - $old_packets) / 10")` is checking the amount of packets received every 10 seconds and storing that value in the variable `rate`?

Comment: `packets` are the sum of all packets since boot. `old_packets` are the sum of packets, 10 seconds ago. `rate` is the packets per seconds. The `bc` line (terminal calculator) is just simple arithmetic

Comment: Okay, so let's say that I wanted to update this every second, how would the code change?

Comment: replace all '10' occurrences by '1'. But divide by 1 is useless

Comment: To specify, I'm working on mitigation methods for DoS attacks, and as I run the DoS attack on my machine, I can see using wireshark that the amount of packets being sent to the VM ip is in the thousands, but the code never seems to enter the if statement `if ((old_packets)); then`

Comment: You need to be root, and run the code like this : `bash -x script.bash`; Maybe reduce the amount of packets (in the if statement) to 5

Comment: Okay, that seems to be doing more things. Is there a way to make this an executable text file? I've tried to locate the `/etc/rc.local' file before, and I don't seem to have one (running Debian 8 I believe)

Comment: `chmod +x script.sh; ./script.sh`. You can create the file if it not exists

Comment: I'm sorry, it still does not seem to be entering the `if ((old_packets)); then` statement, and when I run the command `bash -x script.bash`, the output in the terminal just looks like it's reading off every line before the  `if ((old_packets)); then` line (I.E. `+ old_packets=0', `+ true`, etc.). I'm sorry, and thank you for all your help!

Comment: Have you edited the script with your real interface name instead of `eth0:` ? `awk 'END{print $1}' /proc/net/dev`

Comment: How can I find the name of my interface? I sincerely thought it was eth0...

Comment: Start to understand what you do. Latest command should output your interface name...

Comment: Okay! So I got it working! The only issue I still have is the fact that the line `ip link set eth0 down` tells me that the `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`. How can I get around this? I've already removed the need to use `sudo` by adding the following line to the `visudo` file: `master ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`, but it looks like I need to somehow execute the script without having to type `sudo` in the terminal (I have the terminal running a looping script already so I literally cannot use it to run the .bash file). Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I really appreciate everything you've done to further my research.